# Widgets in a row not spacing themselves out evenly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-row

I'm trying to make a widget to display posts by users on a social media platform, I have certain elements I want to include in the post, one of them being the external links he might have attached while creating the posts.
I want these links to be represented by rounded buttons(which I've managed to achieve through the use of **ClipOval**) and I want these ovals to be in a row spaced evenly from the center.

[image: Here's an image of what I've described and managed to achieve so far]

So far, the only way I've been able to space them out is by adding **SizedBox(s)** of a certain width. But this is not efficient for different posts may differ in the number of links and thus the number of Ovals. This would look messy then.

I have overlaid the row on top of the post's image(to which I've applied a *linear gradient* to make the buttons visible) using a stack.

Here's my code

```
class postTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  List <String> tags = ['tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4','tag5','tag6','tag7','tag8'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 150,),
          Container(
            height: 450,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Card(
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 70.0),
                              child: Text("Username"),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0,left: 80.0),
                              child: Text("Hello"),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Container(
                                  foregroundDecoration:BoxDecoration(
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.transparent],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                            stops: [0, 0.3],
                          ),),
                                    child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/modelPostImage.png'),fit: BoxFit.contain,)),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 10.0,
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(width: 15,),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 56,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              blurRadius: 2.0,
                                              spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                            )
                                          ]
                                        ),
                                        child: ClipOval(
                                          child: Material(// button color
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                                              child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child:Image(
                                                image: new AssetImage("assets/Icons/browser.jpg"),
                                                width: 32,
                                                height:32,
                                                color: null,
                                                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                              ),),
                                              onTap: () {},
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 15,),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 60,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                blurRadius: 2.0,
                                                spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                              )
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        child: ClipOval(
                                          child: Material(// button color
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                                              child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child:Image(
                                                image: new AssetImage("assets/Icons/browser.jpg"),
                                                width: 32,
                                                height:32,
                                                color: null,
                                                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                              ),),
                                              onTap: () {},
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 15,),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 60,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                blurRadius: 2.0,
                                                spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                              )
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        child: ClipOval(
                                          child: Material(// button color
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                                              child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child:Image(
                                                image: new AssetImage("assets/Icons/browser.jpg"),
                                                width: 32,
                                                height:32,
                                                color: null,
                                                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                              ),),
                                              onTap: () {},
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 44,
                            width: 350,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(22))
                            ),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount: tags.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                return Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
                                  ),
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 13, left: 13),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 20, left:20
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(tags[index],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black
                                      ),),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 42,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/Icons/profileLogo.jpg')
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap with a container and give it full width and remove sizing

```
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 10.0,
                        child: Container(
                            width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child :Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 56,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      blurRadius: 2.0,
                                      spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                    )
                                  ]
                                ),
                                child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Material(// button color
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                                      child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child:Image(
                                        image: new AssetImage("assets/Icons/browser.jpg"),
                                        width: 32,
                                        height:32,
                                        color: null,
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      ),),
                                      onTap: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 60,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        blurRadius: 2.0,
                                        spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                      )
                                    ]
                                ),
                                child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Material(// button color
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                                      child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child:Image(
                                        image: new AssetImage("assets/Icons/browser.jpg"),
                                        width: 32,
                                        height:32,
                                        color: null,
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      ),),
                                      onTap: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 60,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        blurRadius: 2.0,
                                        spreadRadius: 1.0,
                                      )
                                    ]
                                ),
                                child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Material(// button color
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                                      child: SizedBox(width: 56, height: 56, child:Image(
                                        image: new AssetImage("assets/Icons/browser.jpg"),
                                        width: 32,
                                        height:32,
                                        color: null,
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      ),),
                                      onTap: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: Works if I want my widget to take up the whole screen's width but this helped me figure it out. I'd have to add a width parameter to my top level container and give the same width to the container you've specified. It involves hard coding the values but gets it done. Only if there was a way to resize it automatically according to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specialized widget to create even space instead of using SizedBox. Replace SizedBox with [Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html).